# mySQL WHERE Clause Shorthand

Tags: mysql, where-clause, shortcut

Is it possible to shorthand mySQL where clause and say :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (animal = cat OR dog OR bird)
```

instead of saying :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (animal = cat OR row = dog OR row = bird)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the  `IN` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE animal in ('cat','dog', 'bird')
```